# PKCS # 11 library in C#

Tags: c#, dll, pkcs#11

I need to write PKCS11 library for some smart-card. I am C# developer and I do not want to use other languages. I use platform invoke to comunicate with cards API (it is no PKCS11).

How can I write library with PKCS11 interface in C# that will be available not only for .Net. What technologies i must use, what i must know (I have never done this things before)?
I hope, I will be enough some keywords in this subject for start. In what direction i must dig?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by will be available not only for .Net ? Does it mean you want it to be used by other languages? If yes, then what languages?

Comment: New readers: please note that C# is very far from a good choice for implementing PKCS#11 libraries. PKCS#11 is a specification for a C interface to security tokens, and it uses "templates" for almost anything. Templates consist of (partially filled in) data structures, which the PKCS#11 interface will fill in. The main data structure is the byte. Its a better idea to read K&R the C language and get on with it.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes we know this, we're just being tasked to do this by those who don't :(

Comment: Well, I designed a partial implementation of PKCS#11 is an even less likely language, so yeah. That was interfaced using C++ though, which would be a nice middle ground I suppose. It's certainly not impossible, but why you would create a C-interface using C# is beyond me - give me an address and I'll send the management a clue-stick.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes what I'm actually doing I now realise is a little different: I'm writing a C# client to use the library/DLL, which was written in C - and it's being a pain in the ass already. I now reread the question and wonder what was on the OP's mind

Comment: Usually for your situation you'd use an existing wrapper like [pkcs11interop](https://pkcs11interop.net/) or [nCryptoki](https://www.ncryptoki.com/). There also have been efforts to create a Microsoft-compatible Cryptographic Service Provider (CSP) around PKCS#11 and there was an O/S adapter for that, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for "[how to create an unmanaged DLL in C#](http://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20create%20an%20unmanaged%20DLL%20in%20C#)". Yet I should say that the idea to create a PKCS#11 driver DLL in C# is far from ideal due to a number of reasons which you will find in articles found using the above search link.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this library: [pkcs11.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pkcs11net/)

> Pkcs11 wrapper for .Net, written in C#. Supported Methods: TokeInfo/SlotInfo, Open/Close Session, Login/Logout, Find Objects, Digest, Sign/Verify, Encrypt/Decrypt

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you want to do this, yet PKCS#11 is not a windows things, CSP is, though some apps use PKCS#11 like Mozilla but I really recommend if you wanna do a PKCS#11, do it in C or C++ just for the code to be portable to other platforms, this might need tweaking (#if #else) of course but the main logic code will stay the same and really PKCS#11 is linux/unix/bsd/macosx thing .. also  C# can't generate a stdlib , I assume it generates a COM/COM+ object which is totally different than a C library for PKCS#11 ..

Comment: I created stdlib wrap for COM/COM+ :)

Comment: That's good as a practice on how to do a COM but not generally useful if you want to do make people use your smartcards except for custom applications (may be,, I would perfer PKCS#11 or CSP) ..  i.e. anyone wants to use your Library shall only use it in a custom Application which imports this COM, it can't be used in any standard app that usually will need to use this smartcard  .. by a standard app I mean " browsers, email client apps, windows apps, kerbros based apps"  which all use either the CSP or PKCS#11

Answer (score 1):

You can use NCryptoki, a C# interface to PKCS#11 unmanaged dll.
See this: http://www.ncryptoki.com

PKCS#11 can be used not only for PKI functions (keys and certificates) but also for storing and reading data in the smart card. This is why PKCS#11 is needed also on Windows.